# How do we resolve ex.Message = "Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue'."?

Tags: c#, mongodb, casting, bson, objectid

All:

Upon insertion in MongoDB database, I'm getting Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue'

```
       ELLCsInterfaceLogEvent aLogEvent = null;
        try
        {

            MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId  UmbrellaLogIdAsObjectId = (ObjectId)UmbrellaLogId;
            BsonDocument logEventBsonDoc = new BsonDocument { 
                                    {"UmbrellaLogId",(BsonValue)UmbrellaLogIdAsObjectId}
                                 }; // end of new BsonDocument
            objUtility = new Utility();
            objUtility.Insert(logEventBsonDoc, "FMS_TM_MST_LogEvents");
            string[] arrFields = { "UmbrellaLogId" };
            IMongoQuery query = Query.EQ("UserID", (BsonValue)UmbrellaLogId);
           aLogEvent = DBConnection.database.GetCollection<ELLCsLogEvent>("FMS_TM_MST_LogEvents")
                                          .Find(query).SetFields(arrFields).ToList<ELLCsInterfaceLogEvent>().FirstOrDefault();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string something = ex.Message;
        }
```

How can I easily cast between Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, for the false alarm.  It was a silly programming mistake.
In my query to check if I inserted the entry, I failed to do a cast.

Here is the correct code:

```
        ELLCsInterfaceLogEvent aLogEvent = null;
        try
        {
            //BsonValue bval = MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue((ObjectId)UmbrellaLogId);
            //new MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue((ObjectId)UmbrellaLogId);
            MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId  UmbrellaLogIdAsObjectId = (ObjectId)UmbrellaLogId;
            BsonDocument logEventBsonDoc = new BsonDocument { 
                                    {"UmbrellaLogId",(BsonValue)UmbrellaLogIdAsObjectId}
                                 }; // end of new BsonDocument
            objUtility = new Utility();
            objUtility.Insert(logEventBsonDoc, "FMS_TM_MST_LogEvents");
            string[] arrFields = { "UmbrellaLogId" };
            IMongoQuery query = Query.EQ("UmbrellaLogId", (BsonValue)UmbrellaLogIdAsObjectId);
           aLogEvent = DBConnection.database.GetCollection<ELLCsLogEvent>("FMS_TM_MST_LogEvents")
                                          .Find(query).SetFields(arrFields).ToList<ELLCsInterfaceLogEvent>().FirstOrDefault();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string something = ex.Message;
        }
        return aLogEvent;
```